# Internal 500 error laravel 5.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have a domain say www.example.com and on the root of the domain I have a folder called development. Inside development I have a folder called hunterlp and inside the hunterlp folder all my laravel files are placed when I navigate to http://www.example.com/development/hunterlp/ i am greeted by a 500 internal server error.

I moved all my folders from public to the hunterlp root folder and placed a .htaccess with the following in

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

How can I make my laravel site work in that folder?

Comment: Did you changed the require paths inside index.php file?

Comment: Does `http://www.example.com/development/hunterlp/index.php` work fine?

Answer (score 0):

please follow this instruction its work for you

```
1. connect to hosting via SSH

2. install composer

3. in cpanel open Select PHP version and choose 5.4. (I also set phar extension)

4. install laravel: php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist

5. copy everything from myproject/public to public_html

6. open public_html/index.php and set:

7. require __DIR__.'/../myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';

8. $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myproject/bootstrap/start.php';
```

for the 7 and 8 steps give the path where you source has so that file find that files

Hope this is works.

Comment: I don't have ssh access, i'm on a shared hosting package